# Reference with compound labels

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

I created an environment, Procedure, using the package `tcolorbox`. The procedures are numbered by `\thechapter-\theproc` and I would like to use `cleveref` to refer to them.

Here is a minimum working example in which I can't figure out how to cross-reference `\label{proc:One}` using `\cref`.

```
    \documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \newcounter{proc}[chapter]
    \newtcolorbox{Procedure}[1]{title=#1}
    \usepackage{cleveref}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \label{ch:First}

    \refstepcounter{proc}
    \label{proc:One}%
    \begin{Procedure}%
    {%begin title
    \emph{\textbf{Procedure \thechapter-\theproc. }}A TITLE%
    }
    Some stuff
    \end{Procedure}

    I would like to refer to the above procedure but neither

    \textbf{Procedure \cref{proc:One}} on \cpageref{proc:One}

    nor

    \textbf{Procedure \labelcref{proc:One}} on \cpageref{proc:One}

    give the hoped-for

    \textbf{Procedure 1-1} on page 1

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mico's answer is good, here is another possibility!

The `cleveref` features are already provided by `tcolorbox`, using the `crefname=` or `Crefname=` options and `label=` as option for the label. The `Procedure` tcolorbox can be slightly redefined.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{proc}%[chapter]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=proc,number within=chapter,crefname={procedure}{procedures},Crefname={Procedure}{Procedures}]{Procedure}[2][]{%
  title={\textbf{\textit{Procedure \thetcbcounter. }}#2},#1}

\begin{document}


\chapter{First}
%\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{Procedure}[label={proc:One}]{A TITLE} 
Some stuff
\end{Procedure}

I would like to cross-reference the above procedure. 

Now, ``\cref{proc:One} on \cpageref{proc:One}'' and
``Procedure \labelcref{proc:One} on \cpageref{proc:One}''
both work and \cref{proc:Two} works two!

\chapter{Second}
\begin{Procedure}[label={proc:Two}]{And now for something completely different}
  Some stuff
\end{Procedure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It works on the Magnum Opus, with a zillion packages including Hyperref! Only one question, out of curiosity: I wanted to try and get, say, Procedure 3.4 boldfaced and have only A TITLE in italics. Didn't make it. What happened, I think, is that I have:        \newtcolorbox[use counter=proc,number within=chapter,crefname={procedure}{procedures},Crefname={Procedure}{Procedures}]{Procedure}[2][]{%
enhanced,arc=0mm,colframe=DarkBlue,colback=LightBlue,coltitle=black,title={\textbf{\textit{Procedure \thetcbcounter. }}#2},#1}

Comment: @schremmer: Try `title={\textbf{Procedure \thetcbcounter. }\textit{#2}}`. But the black font on DarkBlue background is hard to read -- I don't recommend this

Answer (score 4):

You need to inform `cleveref` how to "label" cross-references to items associated with the counter `proc`. One way to do this is use the instruction

```
\crefname{proc}{Procedure}{Procedures}
```

The second and third arguments of the `\crefname` directive should contain the singular and plural forms of the "label".

In the code below, I've also streamlined and simplified the overhead associated with each instance of a `Procedure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{proc}[chapter]
% prefix the 'chapter' counter to 'proc' counter
\renewcommand{\theproc}{\thechapter-\arabic{proc}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% reduce the overhead needed to create title of procedure
\newtcolorbox{Procedure}[1]{%
  title=\textbf{\textit{Procedure \theproc. }}#1}

% automatically increment the 'proc' counter at start of each 'Procedure'
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Procedure}{\refstepcounter{proc}}

% Provide the singular and plural forms of label associated with 'proc' counter
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{proc}{Procedure}{Procedures}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{Procedure}{A TITLE} \label{proc:One}
Some stuff
\end{Procedure}

I would like to cross-reference the above procedure. 

Now, ``\cref{proc:One} on \cpageref{proc:One}'' and
``Procedure \labelcref{proc:One} on \cpageref{proc:One}''
both work.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had tried \crefname but while there indeed was no ??, I still did not get "Procedure 1-1", only what you got, namely "Procedure 1".

Comment: @schremmer - Sorry, I had missed the fact that you want the chapter number to show up in cross-references to `Procedure` environments. I've updated the code to meet your objective. I've also streamlined it a bit to reduce the overhead associated with each instance of a `Procedure`.

Comment: `\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{Procedure}...` will provide the whole counting 'system'. The bad thing about this, that the internal name is different, something like `\tcbcounter` holds the name.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Thanks for this pointer. I knew about the auto-counter option, but decided to stick with (but also streamline) the OP's approach that uses an external counter variable.

Comment: @Mico: No problem -- I even forgot that there's a `crefname` option etc. already provided by `tcolorbox`

Comment: I like both Mico's and Hupfer's solutions and I am going to use Hupfer's only because of my particular circumstances which are that I am embarking on a 1000 pages editing program across three books in which I am going to replace, inter alia, old boxes by tcolorboxes so that his solution seems to require a bit less work. But that's for me and I don't want to give future readers the wrong impression so here is my problem: How can I adopt both answers here? Also: Where can I learn about this "bad thing", internal versus external counter?

Comment: @schremmer: Sorry, I did not see your comment until now: A `\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{foo}` uses a counter named `tcb@cnt@foo`, not `foo`, i.e. accessing the counter name is more difficult and hard to remember.

Comment: @ ChristianHupfer - My fault, having trouble with @. I have started implementing your solution in the magnum opus. Works fine. See <http://freemathtexts.org/InProgress/RAFv7.1/RAFv7.1.pdf> Never had to remember the name of a counter so that's fine too. Auf Wiedersehen.