# Custom reference text for (sub)labels (here for subfigure-like tcolorbox)

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox, labels

For the reasons [floats cannot be nested in tcolorbox](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fllost) and I want my (sub)figure to be fancier, I coded new `Figure` and `Subfigure` newtcolorbox environments. Here is a simplified version of my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}


\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure \ref{fig:#1}}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{Figure}[1]{
    title = {Figure~\thetcbcounter~$-$ #1}
    }
    
\newtcolorbox[
        auto counter,
        number within=tcb@cnt@Figure,
        number freestyle = {(\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter})}
        ]
        {Subfigure}[3][]{
    width = (\linewidth - 4\dimexpr (#2pt - 1pt)\relax)/#2,
    before =,
    after = \hfill,
    box align = center,
    title = {\thetcbcounter~#3},
    #1
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{Figure}
    {Title figure}
    \begin{Subfigure}[label={fig:a}]{2}
        {Title again}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{Subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{Subfigure}{2}
        {A nice Subfigure}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{Subfigure}
\end{Figure}


See \figref{a}.

\end{document}
```

with the output

[image: MWE]

I like the result, but I would like the text to print `Figure 1a` instead of `Figure (a)` and so without changing the title of the subfigure. More precisely, I could change the `number freestyle` argument of newtcolorbox to have `1a` as the counter of my subfigure, but the this would change the title from `(a) blabla` to `1a blabla` which I don't want.

Note that I use `hyperref` package even if I removed it from my Minimal Working Example.

I know a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/defining-custom-labels) has been asked, but I don't know how close from my question it is since I don't understand what

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customlabel}[2]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{}}}}
\makeatother
```

is doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the label format using `\labelformat` (see [`ltnews30.pdf`](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews30.pdf) for more information):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}


\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure \ref{fig:#1}}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{Figure}[1]{
    title = {Figure~\thetcbcounter~$-$ #1}
    }
    
\newtcolorbox[
        auto counter,
        number within=tcb@cnt@Figure,
        number freestyle = {(\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter})}
        ]
        {Subfigure}[3][]{
    width = (\linewidth - 4\dimexpr (#2pt - 1pt)\relax)/#2,
    before =,
    after = \hfill,
    box align = center,
    title = {\thetcbcounter~#3},
    #1
    }

\labelformat{tcb@cnt@Subfigure}{\arabic{tcb@cnt@Figure}\alph{tcb@cnt@Subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Figure}
    {Title figure}
    \begin{Subfigure}[label={fig:a}]{2}
        {Title again}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{Subfigure}%
    %
    \begin{Subfigure}{2}
        {A nice Subfigure}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{Subfigure}
\end{Figure}


See \figref{a}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: I would suggest to also use `cleveref` instead of defining your own `\figref`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you motivate the use of `cleveref` instead of defining my own commands?

Comment: @OursPolaire IMHO this would be another question. See, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291429/277964